# Proof of e as a limit

Tags: calculus

I'm reading this text:

[image]

A few questions:

1. What's the importance of them going from $h$ to $x$ in the first line? What is the difference?
2. How did they go from 
   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x) - \ln(1)}{x}$$
   to
   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{1}{x} \cdot \ln(1+x)\right]$$
3. And then right before the blue 5 box... how did they go from:
   $$e^{\lim_{x \to 0} \ln(1+x)^{1/x}}$$
   to
   $$\lim_{x \to 0} e^{\ln(1+x)^{1/x}}$$
   How did they just pull out the limit sign?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The x-h notations are equivalent.

Note that $\ln 1=0$ thus

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x) - \ln(1)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x} \cdot \ln(1+x)\right)$$

Since the exponential function is continuos $$e^{\lim f(x)}\equiv \lim e^{f(x)}$$

Comment: when the e function is continuous, then e to the exponent is what? what does the three equals mean?

Comment: @Jwan622 It basically means that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x))$ if $f$ is continuous at $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$. So the $\lim$ and $f$ can "switch places". And the $\equiv$ means that they are equivalent.

Comment: @Jwan622 yes it is just as Botond stated!

Comment: @Botond And what does “equivalent” mean? The equality sign is better here.

Comment: @egreg it was just a symbol to describe that it is an equivalent way to take the limit

Comment: @egreg To be honest, I could not even draw it up on my mother tongue.

Comment: Equivalent is often used in situations where "equal" makes no sense.  Equivalency calls for an extra structure that defines the equivlaency.  For example, a square cannot equal a circle, but we can say "this square and this circle are *equivalent* in terms of area."  In this case, "in terms of area" is the equivalency structure.  Where it gets a bit strange is situations like this where = would have worked.  My experience is that ≡ gets used here to indicate that you can *replace* one expression with another, typically using just syntax (what is written) rather than semantics(what is meant)

Comment: I think the usage of ≡ stems from the lower level mathematics (like Structures or Proof Theory), where they use equivalency a lot.  This bubbles up to our level of math in a peculiar way where ≡ seems more "forceful" because the notation comes from those crazy math people who do things like *prove* that 2+2=4 using nothing but symbolic manipulation and proofs.  (Botond, feel free to correct me if this isn't the "feel' you were going for)

Comment: Thank you for your recent comment.

Answer (score 6):

1. There is no difference.
2. $\ln(1)=0$.
3. The exponential function is continuous.